# Logstash remove field after JSON-parsing it

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

Using Logstash 1.4.2 with ElasticSearch 1.3 (I'm aware it's not the latest ES version available) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

We have an event stream which contains JSON inside one of its fields named "message".

We'd like to replace the event fields by the JSON of that field if it's found.

We'd also like to remove the ORIGINAL "message" field (the one which contains the JSON string) if found and parsed.

The problem is that the JSON object inside the field's text could define a new "message" field, which we have to retain.

The following removes the "message" field always after parsing it:

```
json {
  source => "message"
  remove_field => [ "message" ]
}
```

Which is wrong, we want to keep it in case there was a "message" field inside the value of the original "message" field.

I tried to do the following trick, but it seems to still remove the "message" field from the result:

```
mutate {
  rename => [ "message", "___temp_logstash_filter_message___" ]
}
json {
  source => "___temp_logstash_filter_message___"
}
mutate {
  remove_field => [ "___temp_logstash_filter_message___" ]
}
```

i.e. I try to rename the original "message" field to an arbitrary internal name which I don't expect to appear in the input value, parse the JSON string using that temporary name as a source, then remove the renamed original field.

That way I was hoping to distinguish between the "original" message field and any "message" field which may be contained inside its JSON value. But this doesn't seem to make a difference - the "message" field is still missing from the result.

Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Thanks.

Comment: Try putting the original mutate{} in a separate filter{} block.  I've found that this helps with field scope sometimes.

Comment: Also, put the remove_field inside the json{} block, so the temp field will only be removed if it succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Moving the first mutate{} might be a problem because all this is done inside a condition block. About the second mutate{} - I put it explicitly in a separate stanza to make the logic more readable, but I'll try what you say too. BTW - the ___temp_logstash_fileter_message___ field did NOT appear in the output, so I think that this part isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of renaming the field, copy the first field into a new one.

This can be done with:

```
filter {
    ...
    ruby {
        code => "event['new_field'] = event['old_field']"
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still have to find out after the JSON parsing whether the message field should be removed. Perhaps by either renaming it using Ruby or comparing the pre-parse with the post-parse version of the field I'll be able to achieve that?